# comparing big csv files using hashmap or hashset

Tags: java, csv, hashmap, compare, hashset

i'm trying to compare two huge CSV files. First file (id.csv), consists of users ID and second file (data.csv), consists of raw-data. I'm trying to iterate for each id in first file and find all the raw-data of the same id from second file and write in new file. I have tried my simple code as following but i think this will take more than month to process. Please help to implement code that can process faster.

```
    public class FilterUser {

    public static String UniqueUser = "D:/test/id.csv";
    public static String Raw = "D:/test/data.csv";
    public static String OutputFile = "D:/test/output.csv";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        Scanner ScanIn1 = null;
        String users = "";
        String[] record;
        ArrayList<String> InArray = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try{    
        ScanIn1 =  new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(UniqueUser)));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Raw));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(OutputFile));
        bw.write("id,date,time,Use_duration,book1,book2");
        bw.newLine();

        while(ScanIn1.hasNext()){
            users = ScanIn1.nextLine();
            InArray.add(users);
        }
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            record = line.split(",");
            for(int i=0; i<InArray.size(); i++){
                if(InArray.get(i).equals(record[0])){
                    String output = record[0] + "," + record[1] + "," + record[2] + "," + record[3] + "," + record[4]+ "," + record[5];
                    bw.write(output);
                    bw.newLine();
                }
            }
            }

        br.close();
        bw.close();
        ScanIn1.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long TotalTime = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Total time =" + TotalTime);
    }

}
```

**id.csv**

[image: id.csv]

**data.csv**

[image: data.csv]

Comment: Sorting the file would help to reduce the research (using a sorted set an a binary search). You could use a small db to help you doing the join (like SQLITE). Can't really say much more without more information on the files (for this to take month, this should be more than a terabyte of data...). PS: Where are your maps and sets mention in the title ?

Comment: @AxelH yes the first file is 0.5GB and sencond file is 15GB. Actually i mentioned about maps and sets to ask how can i implement those to run this code faster.

Comment: is your id value always a 3 digit number??

Comment: Is it unsurred to be order by ID in both files ? If so, simply iterate both file in the same time.

Comment: @Nithin my id value contains 10 digit number and thank you helping me, i will try with your re-written code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be re-written rplacing arraylist with hashSet. Because using contains() method of hashSet the code becomes efficient. contains() method has an efficiency of O(1). Due to this u can avoid using 2 loops (while and for) for verification.

```java
public class FilterUser {

    public static String UniqueUser = "D:/test/id.csv";
    public static String Raw = "D:/test/data.csv";
    public static String OutputFile = "D:/test/output.csv";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        Scanner ScanIn1 = null;
        String users = "";
        String id = "";
        HashSet<String> InArray = new HashSet<String>();
        String line;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try{    
        ScanIn1 =  new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(UniqueUser)));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Raw));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(OutputFile));
        bw.write("id,date,time,Use_duration,book1,book2");
        bw.newLine();

        while(ScanIn1.hasNext()){
            users = ScanIn1.nextLine();
            InArray.add(users);
        }
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){

            id=line.substring(0, 3);
            if(InArray.contains(id)){
                bw.write(line);
                bw.newLine();
            }
            }

        br.close();
        bw.close();
        ScanIn1.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long TotalTime = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Total time =" + TotalTime);
    }

}
```